# What is the difference between Web App metrics and Application Insights metrics in my Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In my Azure Portal I have two different sets of metrics for the same applications: Web App metrics and AppInsights metrics. What do each of them correspond to?

Answer (score 3):

Web App metrics are a part of the App Service. Application Insights is a service that you can enable. There is a Free plan and a Paid plan. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/10/10/streamlined-integration-of-app-service-and-azure-application-insights/.

Application Insights gives more detailed information and can track much more of the inner details of your application. It is also extendable. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/ for an introduction.